# jquery sortable: sorting in hide list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've 3 sortable list, connected each other. On document ready, just the first one is shown. The others are hidden. I need to create a function that shows the hidden list when an item in the first list is dragged on div which contains the relative list.

```
<div id="box1"> BOX 1
    <ol id="list1">
        <li class="items">item A</li>
        <li class="items">item B</li>
        <li class="items">item C</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="box2"> BOX 2
    <ol id="list2">
        <li class="items">item D</li>
        <li class="items">item E</li>
        <li class="items">item F</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="box3"> BOX 3
    <ol id="list3">
        <li class="items">item G</li>
        <li class="items">item H</li>
        <li class="items">item I</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#list2, #list3").hide();
        $("#list1, #list2, #list3").sortable({
            connectWith: "#list1, #list2, #list3" 
        });   
    })     
</script>
```

So, when i drag an item of the list 1 over box 2, I want call the function `$('#list2').show()`

Answer (score 0):

Add `draggable="true"` as an attribute to all your `<li>` elements.
Then change the script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#list2, #list3").hide();
  $("#box2").on("dragenter", function() {
    $("#list2").show();
  });
  $("#box3").on("dragenter", function() {
    $("#list3").show();
  });
})
```

You'll find more info here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/